# Why is my moving label effect in Vue not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

Hey guys im trying to recreate an effect like this in vue:

[image]

As you can see the labels moves and shows itself when the user begins typing in the input box.

However I'm struggling to access the value inside my input boxes to check if they're empty or not.

**here's my vue template:**

```
<template>
  <div class="desktop-landing-search">
    <!---------------------------------------JOB SEARCH WRAPPER--------------------------------------->
    <div class="desktop-landing-search__search-wrapper">
      <div class="desktop-landing-search__input-box">
        <label for="inputType" ref="typeLabel">Graduate or Internship</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="desktop-landing-search__input-box__input-search"
          id="inputType"
          placeholder="Graduate or Internship"
          ref="inputJobType"
          v-on:input="showLabel('type')"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="desktop-landing-search__input-box">
        <label for="inputIndustry" ref="industryLabel">Industry</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="desktop-landing-search__input-box__input-search"
          id="inputIndustry"
          placeholder="Industry"
          ref="inputIndustry"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="desktop-landing-search__input-box">
        <label for="inputLocation" ref="locationLabel">Location</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="desktop-landing-search__input-box__input-search"
          id="inputLocation"
          placeholder="Location"
          ref="inputLocation"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="desktop-landing-search__input-box">
        <button class="desktop-landing-search__btn-search">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**here's the method i call to show the label:**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "DesktopLandingSearch",
  methods: {
    showLabel: function(input) {
      if (this.input === "type" && this.refs.inputJobType.value != "") {
        this.refs.typeLabel.classList.toggle("show-label");
        window.alert("testing job type");
      }
      if (this.input === "industry" && this.refs.inputIndustry.value != "") {
        this.refs.industryLabel.classList.toggle("show-label");
        window.alert("test job industry");
      }
      if (this.input === "location" && this.refs.inputLocation.value != "") {
        this.refs.locationLabel.classList.toggle("show-label");
        window.alert("test job location");
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**And this is the class I want to toggle:**

```
.show-label {
  top: -130%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into `v-model`?

If you put `v-model="inputIndustry"` on that input, then above your methods put:

```
data() {
  return {
    inputIndustry: ""
  }
}
```

Whatever is typed in the input is inserted or 'binded' to the `inputIndustry` data property.

So, in `showLabel` you can check if `this.inputIndustry !== ""` and then do whatever you like.

If you remove all the references to the `input` parameter and replace them with references to your binded data properties, you can access the input values directly. You'll need to put `@keydown="showLabel"` on each input as well so that method gets triggered.

Docs are a good help if you need them: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Look into class binding with `v-bind` too if you want to toggle classes: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Comment: Had a play around and I think ```e.target``` is a better solution. Here's a rough demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Knights/4ux0tbd7/32/

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Just one question though, I'm passing a parameter in when I am calling showLabel, for example @keydown="showLabel('location')". But when I debug it says the location parameter is undefined, am I using the wrong brackets or something?

Comment: Nevermind i've fixed it. when accessing the parameter in the method i was writing 'this.input' but should i just used 'input'.

Comment: Are you using the ```e.target``` way? If so, you'll need to say ```@keydown="showLabel($event, 'location'"``` and add the parameter for 'location' in ```showLabel(e, input)```

Comment: Oh yep, that too